# Search Engine Necessary?

Tags: django, database, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

In my application, I have a bunch of service providers in my database offering various services. I need a user to be able to search through these service providers by either name, location, or both. I also need a user to be able to filter the providers by different criteria, based on multiple attributes.

I am trying to decide if I could implement this simply with database queries or if a more robust solution (i.e. a search engine) would better suit my needs.

Please let me know the pros and cons of either solution, and which you think would be best to go with.

I am writing my application in Django 1.7, using a PostGIS database, and would use django-haystack with elasticsearch if a search engine is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy,It seems that you are working on a search intensive application.Now my opinion in this regard is as follows-:

1)If u use search intensive queries directly with the database,Then automatically overhead is gonna be very high as each time a separate criteria based query is to be fired to the database engine from your django.Each time query is to be built with seperate parameters and is to be built to fire at the backend database engine. Consequence is it will make you highly dependent on the availability of database server.Things can go more worse if database server will be  located in some remote location.As overhead of network connectivity will be another addendum to this.

2)You should try to implement a server side caching system like redis that is a in-memory nosql database (sometimes also called a data structure server) that will beat all the problems I discussed in my previous point.Read more about it [here](http://redis.io/).

3)To powerpack your search.Read about Apache Solr [enter link description here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).A lucene  based search library this will power pack your search to the next level.

4)Last but not least go with case studies of biggies like facebook,twitter etc regarding how they are managing their infrastructure.You will get even more better idea.

Any doubts or suggestions.Kindly comment    cheers :-)

Comment: Ok, sounds like using a search engine is the way to go. Django-haystack makes this fairly simple to implement in django. Thanks for the input.